# Create an extension method to override from different classes

Tags: c#, class, overriding, extension-methods, tostring

I have different classes that all overrides `ToString()` function and they all use the same logic

And what I'm doing now is that I'm calling a static method for of those classes and I wanted to know  its possible to create an extension method that will be called from those all those `ToString()` methods

This is what I have so far

```
 public class A
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Helper.myToString(this);
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Helper.myToString(this);
        }
    }
```

and `myToString()`

```
public static string myToString(object obj)
{
 ///do stuff
}
```

I created an extension method like this

static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static  string myStoString(this object  obj) 
        {
            //do stuff
        }
     }

but I don't know how to call it or if it's even possible

Comment: Remember you need to declare the extension method in a separate static class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach is OK.

Extension method is the static method too. There won't be any difference at runtime, just a syntax one:

`this.myToString()`

instead of

`Helper.myToString(this)`

Since writing extension methods for `object` isn't a good choice (it will be available for everything), `Helper` class is preferable.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain more about writing extension methods for object isn't a good choice?

Comment: Every type in .NET is derived from `System.Object`. In your case one will be able to write `123.myToString()` or `"foo".myToString()`, because either `int` or `string` are `object`s too.  I doubt you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty interface like this:

```
public interface IPrintable { }
```

Now change your class declaration to make them implementing that interface

```
public class A : IPrintable
{
  // ...
}

public class B : IPrintable
{
  // ...
}
```

Because interface is empty no other changes required. Then you can write an extension method to `IPrintable`

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string MyToString(this IPrintable printable)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
// will work
var a = new A();
a.MyToString();

// will not work
var c = 10;
c.MyToString();
```